# PHP -v No such file or directory

Tags: php, php7

i've been install PHP7.2 on my PC but when i try to `php -v` it's show me error like this

`bash: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory`

and then i try to type `php7.2 -v` it's works

Anyone have solution so when i type php -v it's show me php7.2 ?

Comment: What does `type -a php` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply install the php alternative package
(https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php)

```
sudo apt install php
```

And you will get new symbolic links

```
~$ ll /usr/bin/php7.2 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.7M Apr 18 16:12 /usr/bin/php7.2*

~$ ll /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar  7 17:05 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php*

~$ ll /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar  7 17:05 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.2*

~$ php -v
PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2019 14:12:38) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

~$ php7.2 -v
PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2019 14:12:38) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```